# Using jquery to remove background image from a particular list

Tags: jquery, css

How to remove background image from a particular list withing a -ul- which has class: dfwp-list ?  ..My code is not working

```
$("ul.dfwp-list > li").css('background-image':'none');
```

[image]

Comment: comma, not semicolon. `.css('background-image','none');` You can use a semicolon when you pass an object, ex `.css({'background-image':'none'});`

Comment: @j08691 -- It is colon, actually; not semicolon.

Comment: @31piy yup, but too late for me to edit the comment

Answer (score 3):

The syntax of calling [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method is wrong. You need to pass it two arguments, or wrap the arguments in object literal (`{}`):

```
$("ul.dfwp-list > li").css('background-image', 'none');

// OR
$("ul.dfwp-list > li").css({'background-image': 'none'});
```

Comment: These didn't work. something else wrong with the code maybe